# Assignment from incompatible pointer type error

Tags: c, pointers

These are the structs I have. Think of linked lists in C.

```
/**
 * The WordNode struct is used to represent a node in a linked list of
 * words. It is defined in this file because it is used only within this
 * file. It is used only as part of the implementation of a word set.
 */
typedef struct WordNode WordNode;
struct WordNode {
  int       freq;   // The frequency of the the word.
  char     *word;   // The word itself.
  WordNode *next;   // The next word node in the list.
};

/**
 * A WordSet struct is used to represent a "set". We are implementing a set as
 * a linked list of WordNodes.
 */
struct WordSet {
  int       size;   // The number of elements in the set.
  WordNode *head;   // The starting node in the set.
};
```

Now, I've got a search function in my file,

```
static WordNode **search (WordSet *wset, char *word) {
  // TODO: This function will return the address of the cell containing the
  // pointer to the WordNode for the given word, or else the address of the
  // cell containing NULL marking the end of the list.  Note that the cell in
  // question can be either the `head` field of the WordSet struct or the
  // `next` field of some WordNode.
  //
  // Hints:
  // (1) p can start by pointing to the `head` field

  WordNode **p = wset->head;

  // if word is in head
  if ((*p) != NULL){
    if (strcmp((*p)->word, word)){
      return p;
    }
  }

  while ((*p)->next != NULL){
    if (strcmp((*p)->next->word, word)){
      return p;
    }
    p = (*p)->next;
  }

  // put loop here
  return p;
}
```

I get the warning: Assignment from incompatible pointer type error p = wset->head

From my understanding, **p means that this is a pointer to a pointer. So, when I initialize p as p = wset->head, I am basically initializing the pointer p to the pointer head, so it is a pointer to a pointer. Why am I still getting the incompatible pointer type error?

I'm also a little confused about the way I'm referencing stuff inside the WordNode. For example, when I do something like (*p)->next, is this the correct way to access the 'next' pointer?

Comment: No.  that is not correct.  wset->head is of type WordNode*, not WordNode**.

Comment: Hm, okay. Is there a way to make p point to the head field without changing its type?

Comment: Yes. Declare it properly as `WordNode*`, just as @OldProgrammer said.

Comment: Why?  Just change **p to *p.  There is no need for double indirection.  C and pointers can be a difficult concept to grasp at first.  I would recommend reading up on that - http://boredzo.org/pointers/

Comment: Lets assume I can't change the declaration of p. What if it absolutely have to be a double pointer, as part of the challenge?

Comment: Or, `WordNode **p = &(wset->head);`

Comment: then change to  WordNode **p = &(wset->head);

Comment: Great minds think alike...